# Can I mix font weights in the same paragraph when using pdfkit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, node-pdfkit

I'm trying to find a way to use **bold font weights** for inline emphasis in **[pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/)**

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to change the font without forcing a line break (bad for inline emphasis...).

I was trying something like:

```
pdf.text('Hello ', LEFT, 200).font(bold).text('World!');
```

but this will output

> Hello
>
> **World**

I also digged through the source but could not find any option to prevent this.

Anyone has any idea or workaround to tackle this problem?

**EDIT**:

All I could come up with by now is a ugly hack looking like this:

```
pdf.text('Hello ', LEFT, 200).moveUp(1).font(bold).text('World!', {indent: pdf.widthOfString('Hello ')});
```

which is working but far from flexible and maintainable.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The documented way to handle this is **continued**.

```
pdf.font('Helvetica-Bold').text('Hello ', {
    continued: true
}).font('Helvetica').text('World!');
```

http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html

Comment: This should be set as the real solution. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Basically you need to set options with lineBreak : false,

```
pdf.text('Hello ', LEFT, 200, {
    //here it is, 
    lineBreak : false
}).font(bold).text('World!');
```

This will make the Hello not break line, so the next World will print on the same line.

I found this in:

```
node_modules\pdfkit\js\mixins\text.js, line 130
```

pdfkit version: 0.2.6

Comment: Great! Interesting though that this is not mentioned at all in the docs: http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#styling

Comment: Even though it works for the same line, it mess up the next line.